# Can't override clientCache@cacheControlMaxAge in web.config

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-config

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="public"></clientCache>
```

However, the browser reports the following in the response:

```
Cache-Control:public,max-age=86400
```

Even stranger, the applicationHost.config has it as follows:

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
```

So I'm not sure where the 86400 (1 day) is coming from, and how to override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a response from [Mamba Dai](http://forums.iis.net/p/1192707/2040588.aspx/1?Re+Can+t+override+clientCache+cacheControlMaxAge) on [forums.iis.net](http://forums.iis.net), I discovered that the virtual directories under the website root had their own cache expiry settings which is where the overriding value was coming from.